# is it possible to ignore some markers when using GoogleMaps onMarkerClickListener, so the click listener isn't even triggered?

Tags: android, google-maps

In the map below I have three markers, the red one is the users current position while the green ones are the clickable markers.

Clicking the bottom one is not a problem. But clicking the one the user is close to is a different matter as the position marker is in the way. So for that one the user usually has to click 2 - 8 times before the green one is touched.

[image]

Is there a way to define that some markers are not clickable so they dont trigger the onMarkerClickListener?

I am aware that I can change the z-index and put the position marker below but it wont be nice for the user if he can't see his own position when close to another marker.

Another solution can think of but dont like is to intercept the click for the user marker and then go through a list of the other markers and find possible matches and trigger a click myself. I'd prefer an existing solution.

Comment: @AbdulKawee https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener is set on the map not the marker object. Is there another way you know of to add specific listeners?

Comment: @AbdulKawee https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker  has no possibility of adding individual listener from what I can see.

Comment: The short answer to Q is no - but from your requirements I'd say offsetting "nearby" markers with a connecting pole would be a good approach - parting-of-the-sea kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I have ended up doing is adding the object the marker represents to its tag. Then in onMarkerClickListener I check the marker type by the tag object. Like so (kotlin):

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener { marker ->
    val mapEvent: MapEvent?
    mapEvent =
            if (marker.tag is MapEvent) {
                marker.tag as MapEvent?
            } else {
                val clickedMarker = getClickedMarker(from = map)
                if (clickedMarker != null)
                    clickedMarker.tag as MapEvent?
                else
                    return@setOnMarkerClickListener false
            }
    markerClicked(this@MainActivity, mapEvent)
    true
}
```

If the object is of type MapEvent I call markerClicked() if the clicked marker is not of type MapEvent I go through a list of all markers to see if the clicked marker is inside the radius of any of the MapEvent markers. If so I use that marker and call markerClicked().

This is how I sort through the list of markers:

```
fun getClickedMarker(from: GoogleMap): Marker? {
    if (!::userMarker.isInitialized)
        return null

    var clickWidth = ContextCompat.getDrawable(App.context, R.drawable.ic_map_permanent)!!.intrinsicWidth
    clickWidth += (clickWidth / 3)

    val g0 = from.projection.fromScreenLocation(Point(0, 0))
    val g1 = from.projection.fromScreenLocation(Point(clickWidth, clickWidth))

    val latRadius = (g1.latitude - g0.latitude) / 2
    val lonRadius = (g1.longitude - g0.longitude) / 2

    return try {
        eventMarkers.single {
            it.position!!.latitude - latRadius > userMarker.position.latitude && // west
                    it.position!!.latitude + latRadius < userMarker.position.latitude && // east
                    it.position!!.longitude + lonRadius > userMarker.position.longitude && // north
                    it.position!!.longitude - lonRadius < userMarker.position.longitude // south
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null
    }
}
```

Please comment if anything is unclear. I hope this might help anyone else!